# How to structure my XText terminals? WORDS/SL_STRING/ML_STRING

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext

In my XText DSL, I want to be able to use three different kinds of text terminals. They are all used for adding comments on top of arrows drawn in a UML diagram:

terminal *WORD*:

`Actor -> Actor: WORD`

terminal *SL_STRINGS*:

`Actor -> Actor: A sequence of words on a single line`

terminal *ML_STRINGS*:

```
    Actor -> Actor: A series of words on 
                      multiple 
                      lines
```

My initial approach was to use the *ID* terminal from the `org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals` as my *WORD* terminal, and then just have *SL_STRINGS* be `(WORD)*`, and *ML_STRINGS* be `(NEWLINE? WORD)*`, but this creates a lot of problems with ambiguity between the rules.

How would I go about structuring this in a good way?

---

More information about the project. (And as this is the first time working with XText, please bear with me):

I am trying to implement a DSL to be used together with the Eclipse Plugin for PlantUML http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/sequence.html mainly for Syntax Checking and Colorization. Currently my grammar works as such:

```
Model:
    (diagrams+=Diagram)*;

Diagram:
    '@startuml' NEWLINE (instructions+=(Instruction))* '@enduml' NEWLINE*
;
```

An instruction can be lots of things:

```
Instruction: 
((name1=ID SEQUENCE name2=ID (':' ID)?) 
| Definition (Color)?
| AutoNumber
| Title
| Legend
| Newpage
| AltElse
| GroupingMessages
| Note
| Divider
| Reference
| Delay
| Space
| Hidefootbox
| Lifeline
| ParticipantCreation
| Box)? NEWLINE
;
```

Example of rules that need different kinds of text terminals:

```
Group:
'group' TEXT
;

Reference:
    'ref over' ID (',' ID)* ((':' SL_TEXT)|((ML_TEXT) NEWLINE 'end ref'))
;
```

For Group, the text can only be on one line, while for Reference, the text can be on two lines if there is no ":" follwing the rule call.

Currently my terminals look like this:

```
terminal NEWLINE    : ('\r'? '\n');

// Multiline comment begins with /', and ends with '/
terminal ML_COMMENT : '/\'' -> '\'/';

// Singleline comment begins with ', and continues until end of line.
terminal SL_COMMENT : '\'' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;

// INT is a sequence of numbers 0-9.
terminal INT returns ecore::EInt: ('0'..'9')+;

terminal WS         : (' '|'\t')+;

terminal ANY_OTHER: .;
```

And I want on top of this to add to this add three new terminals that takes care of the text.

Comment: I'm afraid this question cannot be answered without information about the complete grammar and complete sample files. Please provide more information.

Comment: Added more information in the original post!

Comment: Please avoid spaces in keywords, too, e.g. 'ref over' should be 'ref' 'over'. I think it is sufficient to make WORD and SL_WORD / ML_WORD data type rules rather than terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a data type rule in order to achieve the desired behavior.
Sebastian wrote an excellent blog post on this topic which can be found here: http://zarnekow.blogspot.de/2012/11/xtext-corner-6-data-types-terminals-why.html

Here is a minimal example of a grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Example' ':' comment=Comment;

Comment:
    (ID ('\r'? '\n')?)+ 
;
```

That will allow you to write something like this:

```
Example: A series of words

Example: A series of words on
    multiple lines
```

You then may want to implement your own [value converter](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#value-converter) in order to fine-tune the conversion to a String.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: When trying this in for example the rule `Reference:
    'ref over' ID (',' ID)* ((':' ID*)|((Comment) NEWLINE 'end ref'))
;` I get problems with `no viable alternative at input \r\n` right at the first newline i enter after "ref over bob" if I try to enter for example `ref over bob \r\n hello \r\n end ref `. Any idea why?

Comment: There is nothing the parser can match. Try to parse the example yourself: you can parse the keyword `ref over` and then the ID `bob`. After that what do you do? There is no path that allows a `\r\n` at this point. Usually the parser could match the `WS` rule (from the common.Terminals) but in your grammar you overrode those. If you want a quick hack you can use `Reference:
 'ref' 'over' ID (',' ID)* ((':' ID*) | (NEWLINE? Comment 'end' 'ref'));` but I would strongly recommend to use the default `WS` rule and be less restrictive where your user can insert linebreaks. Use the formatter instead.

Comment: Changed to `Reference: 'ref' 'over' ID (',' ID)* ((':' ID*)|(NEWLINE Comment 'end' 'ref'));`, but it still complains about `mismatched \r\n expecting end` at the first line of text I write after the ID.
Also since I did not specify the language, some diagrams break when you insert random newlines, which was the reason for me removing it from `WS`. Your solution worked wonders in many other areas of my code though! Pretty much only `ref over` that is messing with me now...